# Store sql query output in a excel file

Tags: sql-server

Store sql query output in a excel file

Answer (score 1):

In SQlTip article some one has suggested following approach.You can find original article [here.](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1202)

Exporting data from SQL Server to Excel can be achieved in a variety of ways.  Some of these options include Data Transformation Services (DTS), SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) and Bulk Copy (BCP).  Data Transformation Services (SQL Server 2000) and SQL Server Integration Services (SQL Server 2005) offers a GUI where widgets can be dragged and dropped Each option has advantages and disadvantages, but all can do the job.  It is just a matter of your comfort level with the tools and the best solution to meet the need.

Another option that is available directly via the T-SQL language is the OPENROWSET command (SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005).  This command can be called directly in any stored procedure, script or SQL Server Job from T-SQL.  Below outlines the full syntax available:

```
OPENROWSET 
( { 'provider_name' , { 'datasource' ; 'user_id' ; 'password' 
   | 'provider_string' } 
      , {   [ catalog. ] [ schema. ] object 
       | 'query' 
     } 
   | BULK 'data_file' , 
       { FORMATFILE = 'format_file_path' [ <bulk_options> ]
       | SINGLE_BLOB | SINGLE_CLOB | SINGLE_NCLOB }
} ) 
<bulk_options> ::=
   [ , CODEPAGE = { 'ACP' | 'OEM' | 'RAW' | 'code_page' } ] 
   [ , ERRORFILE = 'file_name' ]
   [ , FIRSTROW = first_row ] 
   [ , LASTROW = last_row ] 
   [ , MAXERRORS = maximum_errors ] 
   [ , ROWS_PER_BATCH = rows_per_batch ]
```

Source - SQL Server 2005 Books Online

Below is a simple example of writing out the Job name and date to Sheet1 of an Excel spreadsheet in either SQL Server 2005 or 2000:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\testing.xls;',
'SELECT Name, Date FROM [Sheet1$]')
SELECT [Name], GETDATE() FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs
GO
```

Using the OPENROWSET command creates two caveats.  The first caveat is the need to have an Excel spreadsheet serve as a template in the needed directory with the correct worksheets and columns.  Without this the you would receive an error message.  The second caveat is that it is necessary to enable the OPENROWSET command with the SQL Server 2005 Surface Area Configuration utility.  Note - This step is not needed for SQL Server 2000. With the loop example you could copy and paste the Excel spreadsheet and load the data as needed.

Although the example above is very simple, you could integrate this simple example into your code.  For example, if you had the need to write out a number of reports in the same format, you could loop (WHILE loop or Cursor) over the records and write them out to different Excel spreadsheets based on the name or report type.   In addition, you could integrate this code with either SQL Server 2000 mail or Database mail (SQL Server 2005) and mail the results to the users with very little effort and build the process entirely with T-SQL.

Comment: I get '''The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" has not been registered.'''

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2008 Management Studio, you can right click on a result pane and choose "Save Results As..." and then choose "CSV - comma-separated value file".

This CSV file can be easily opened in any Excel version.

In SQL Server Management Studio (versions 2005 and up), you could also right-click on the result pane, choose "Select All", then select "Copy" and just paste those values into an open Excel worksheet.

Marc

Comment: In that case we will loose Column Titles.

Comment: In SQL Server Mgmt Studio 2008, there's also a "Copy with Headers" option (not in 2005, unfortunately)

Comment: But in SQL Srv Mgmt Studio 2005, there's an option you can set to include headers in your copy operations all the time

Comment: @marc_s : +1 thanks for the information. Now I will suggest this approach compared to mine.

Comment: Hey, What if I have to do it programatically .. say too many sp_help or sp_helptext 'tables or view'. then?

Answer (score 0):

Most database engines have an export option-> export as a CVS file.

Excel is able to read [csv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.csv) files, and you are able to convert this csv file easily into excel files in by using "save as" button.

However, database like mysql and directly output excel file.

If you want to output excel file from your sql, I suggest you to output a csv file from your query, and use excel after that.